# Triple integral in using spherical coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I have a problem which is related to the triple integral. In details:

Calculate the triple integral $$\iiint\limits_{V} ydxdydz$$ in which V is the sphere: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2y$

I think that it is a better way to solve this problem by using the spherical coordinate. I have tried to solve in this way but I got this integral equal to zero. I think I am wrong because y is not symmetric due to this domain.

Comment: You mean to say, "spherical coordinates" rather than "polar coordinates," but anyway, can't you make a change of variables?  Set $u=y-1$.

Comment: The hint by @saulspatz is good, but it's also possible to use origin-centered spherical coordinates; see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978512/volumes-using-triple-integration.

Comment: I think the best way is completing the square and using saulspatz's change of variables together with spherical, as your region is $x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2\le1.$

Comment: @MaximGilula I agree with you. I don't need to change variable $u = y - 1$ to solve this but still get the limits of $r$, $\varphi$, and $\phi$.

Comment: True. So you are interested in seeing what the limits are without changing $u=y-1?$

Comment: @MaximGilula What do you think about the limits for the original spherical coordinate? I figure out that $0 \leq \varphi \leq 2 \pi$, $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \leq r \leq 2 sin{\varphi} sin{\phi}$. I don't know if I am right?

Comment: I don't like either angle limit because they don't seem to follow from any algebraic nor geometric considerations. What is your reason behind them? Every limit always follows from some algebra from functions given to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if you want regular spherical coordinates: $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2,$ and $2y=2\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi).$

So the only information about limits you have is $\rho^2=2\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi).$ One solution is $\rho=0.$ The other is $\rho=2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),$ as you said. Now it's a tiny bit trickier. You get the next bounds by setting the $\rho$ bounds equal: $0=2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi).$ The solutions are $\theta=n\pi$ or $\phi=0$ or $\phi=\pi.$ So $0\le \phi\le \pi$ is correct, and you have $0\le \theta\le\pi$ as well.

The integral becomes
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)} \rho^3 \sin(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi=4\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \sin^5(\theta)\sin^6(\phi)\,d\theta\,d\phi.$$
Now I'll just use the facts $\int_0^\pi \sin^5(x)\,dx=16/15$ and $\int_0^\pi \sin^6(x)\,dx=5\pi/16$ to get the final answer.

You can check this with the easier integral using the additional substitution of $u=y-1:$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 (\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)+1)\rho^2\sin(\phi)\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$$ $$=\frac{4\pi}{3}+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 \rho^3\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\theta)\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$
since the integral of $\sin(\theta)$ is zero on that interval. It's the same answer.

Comment: I disagree with you that $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$. I think it must be $0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean $\theta$, not $\phi$

Comment: What is your reasoning for this? If you don't like the algebra, the geometry says that $y-1$ shifts everything over up by $1$ unit. Therefore the projection is a circle tangent to the $x-$axis where $y>0.$

Comment: So when do you think $\theta$ get max from 0 to $\pi$?

Comment: Letting $z=0,$ you get the region $x^2+(y-1)^2\le 1.$ This region is represented by $0\le \theta\le \pi,$ and $0\le r\le 2\sin(\theta).$ The $y-$ value is a maximum (is this what you are asking?) when $\theta=\pi/2.$ But the $\theta$ maximum is $\theta=\pi$ when $x=-1$.